# Restapi integration into HDFS

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Hello friends my Question is that I have a usecase where I have to pull data from Restapi which has lots of tweet kind of data(messages). My approach for this usecase is Gethttp -->puthdfs using which have to create Dashboard. What should be the best approach according to your experience as the website is https how to create SSL context for free. Any Help is Appreciable....thanks

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked and answered here:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/9509/connecting-to-datasift-https-api-using-nifi.html

The same approach would be required to create an SSL Context as described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Bryan would try this url it seems useful